# Merging time periods - php

Tags: php

I have the info (start timestamp and finish timestamp) on the each red marked period.

[image: erg]

what I want to achieve is this:
[image]

The final period should contain also number of merged periods as shown in blue span.

I've tried iterating each minute since min and max values but I guess that's not optimal way to solve this.
I'm actually running out of ideas here : (
Example data:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2018-11-8 09:00
        [startTimestamp] => 1541664000
        [finish] => 2018-11-8 15:00
        [finishTimestamp] => 1541685600
        [machine_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2018-11-8 01:30
        [startTimestamp] => 1541637000
        [finish] => 2018-11-8 05:30
        [finishTimestamp] => 1541651400
        [machine_id] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2018-11-8 10:00
        [startTimestamp] => 1541667600
        [finish] => 2018-11-8 18:30
        [finishTimestamp] => 1541698200
        [machine_id] => 4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2018-11-8 09:00
        [startTimestamp] => 1541664000
        [finish] => 2018-11-8 15:00
        [finishTimestamp] => 1541685600
        [machine_id] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2018-11-8 01:30
        [startTimestamp] => 1541637000
        [finish] => 2018-11-8 05:30
        [finishTimestamp] => 1541651400
        [machine_id] => 5
    )
```

Answer thanks to @solarc

```
        $startEndTimes = [];
    foreach ($periodsData as $periodsDatum) {
        $startEndTimes[$periodsDatum['startTimestamp']]  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $periodsDatum['startTimestamp']);
        $startEndTimes[$periodsDatum['finishTimestamp']] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $periodsDatum['finishTimestamp']);
    }

    $split = [];
    foreach ($periodsData as $periodsDatum) {
        foreach ($startEndTimes as $timestamp => $dateTime) {
            if ($timestamp < $periodsDatum['finishTimestamp'] AND $timestamp > $periodsDatum['startTimestamp']) {
                $split[] = [
                    'machine_id'      => $periodsDatum['machine_id'],
                    'startTimestamp'  => $periodsDatum['startTimestamp'],
                    'finishTimestamp' => $timestamp,
                    'start'           => $periodsDatum['start'],
                    'finish'          => date('Y-n-j H:i:s', $timestamp),
                ];
                $split[] = [
                    'machine_id'      => $periodsDatum['machine_id'],
                    'startTimestamp'  => $timestamp,
                    'finishTimestamp' => $periodsDatum['finishTimestamp'],
                    'start'           => date('Y-n-j H:i:s', $timestamp),
                    'finish'          => $periodsDatum['finish'],
                ];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data please?

Comment: yeah sure, i'll edit answer in a sec

Comment: @Slay33, Please, provide us with code you've already written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a set of all the start and end times (without duplicates)

   ```
   [01:30, 05:30, 09:00, 10:00, 14:00, 18:30]
   ```
2. Split each block if there's a time from the set between its own start and end times (so for example the block from 09:00 to 15:00 is split into 2: 09:00 to 10:00 and 10:00 to 15:00):

   ```
       - 01:30 to 05:30 (col 1)
       - 09:00 to 10:00 (col 1)
       - 10:00 to 15:00 (col 1)
       - 10:00 to 15:00 (col 2)
       - 15:00 to 18:30 (col 2)
       - 01:30 to 05:30 (col 3)
       - 09:00 to 10:00 (col 3)
       - 10:00 to 15:00 (col 3)
       - 10:00 to 15:00 (col 4)
       - 15:00 to 18:30 (col 4)
   ```
3. Finally, count how many blocks are repeated across columns:

   ```
       - 01:30 to 05:30 (2 times)
       - 09:00 to 10:00 (2 times)
       - 10:00 to 15:00 (4 times)
       - 15:00 to 18:30 (2 times)
   ```

Comment: That's actually quite genius, thank you. Added my code answer to the question.